# Remove everything after string, but not including that string

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm using vmrun list to grab all the running vms on my machine, but I only want the directory name. Currently the output is

```
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx
```

I want

```
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm
```

I know I can use

```
vmrun list|sed s/vmwarevm.*//
```

But that also removes vmwarevm. Is there a way to do this so that vmwarevm doesn't get removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo "/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx" | sed -r 's/(.*)\/.*/\1/g'
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm
```

But there is also `dirname` command exists:

```
$ dirname "/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx" 
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm
```

Comment: When I try this, I get sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: Well, `-r` is specific flag for GNU sed. Maybe you have BSD one.

Answer (score 5):

Use `dirname`:

```
$ dirname "/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx"
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm
```

Comment: Oh, by the way: ``mypath='--my-cool-path/to/file'; dirname "$mypath" #fail``. You should add `--` after dirname.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good (I would probably use `dirname`), but this can also be done with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)  [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ p="/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx"
$ echo "${p%/*[!/]}"
/path/to/vm.vmwarevm
$
```

Comment: That is the best answer, I wonder why does it have only one vote... All other answers suggest you to run separate tools (Like ``sed`` or ``dirname``), but this answer provides you a pure bash solution with no overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Using shell build-in function ( I prefer this way)

```
p="/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx"
echo ${p%/*}
```

Using sed (without -r option)

```
echo "/path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx" | sed 's#/[^/]*$##'
```

By the way, `dirname` and `basename` don't work in some Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo /path/to/vm.vmwarevm/vm.vmx | xargs dirname
```